# EditText hint shows extra spaces when inputType="textpassword"

Tags: android, android-edittext

Just wondered, am I the only one to encounter this "strange" behavior.

When placing an EditText inside my activity and setting its 
inputType="textPassword"  as follow:

```
<EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText01" 
            android:hint="This is a hint" android:inputType="textPassword" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

The hint is displayed with bigger/double spaces between the words.

If I remove the inputType attribute it all goes back to normal. 
I couldn't find a known issue regarding this behavior.

BTW- If you wonder why this is important (it isn't that much) try 
putting two EditText widgets one below the other and set the inputType 
of one of them to "textpassword" it doesn't look good. 
Any idea on how to change the password or the other edittexts to use the same format ?

Thanks

PS. The question was added here first: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/88738bb8d8046f6f but I didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 9):

It happens because typeface automatically setted to monospace in case of password field. Setting  `android:typeface="normal"` on password field doesn't helps.

Here code from [TextView sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#901):

```
if (password) {
    setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    typefaceIndex = MONOSPACE;
} else if ((mInputType&(EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS
            |EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION))
            == (EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                    |EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)) {
    typefaceIndex = MONOSPACE;
}
```

I can't find solution without implementing custom control with overriden typeface for hint.

P.S.: There is one solution, but it is not always acceptable - to set typeface to monospace on other EditText's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me. For me worked the typeface="monospace" solution. The thing was only to be the same everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Doing `mEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Nice solution. I struggled 4 hrs for this and finally got this one thank budy